# Running and adding ckeditor in rails_admin

Tags: devise, ckeditor, rails-admin, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm doing some research and I've found that you can add a ckeditor in the rails admin, but my problem is that it doesn't seem to show it in the rails_admin. My current version is 4.1 and the other versions or the other solutions were way back in 2010, so the code doesn't seem to work with mine.

Here is the picture:

[image]

I have also done the following:

```
gem 'paperclip'
rails generate ckeditor:install --orm=active_record --backend=paperclip
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/models/ckeditor)
mount Ckeditor::Engine => '/ckeditor'
//= require ckeditor/init



RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.model user do
    edit do
    field :description, :ck_editor
    ckeditor true
   end
  end
end
```

Also please note that I have also used devise and the default user, any help will do and thanks really hard to make this work properly

Answer (score 0):

everything worked after finding out that i didnt need the

```
ckeditor true
```

also after restarting the server